# What subspace is the projection matrix P projecting on?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am given a projection matrix P and asked to find the subspace onto which it is projects.
$$P=\frac{1}{21}\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & -4\\
2 & 4 & -8\\
-4 & -8 & 16
\end{matrix}\right]$$
I know $P = A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^T$ but I don't see how I could solve for A from here. Any tips as to how this could be done would be helpful.

Comment: What would the span of the columns be?

Comment: The second two are linear combinations of the first, so it would just span [1 2 -4]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $P= {1 \over 21} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\2 \\ -4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 &2 & -4 \end{bmatrix} $.

Hence ${\cal R}P = \operatorname{sp} \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\2 \\ -4 \end{bmatrix}  \} $

Comment: Ah, ok, I get it!